# How to delete high score of the gnome-mines game?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, games

I want to delete the high score of gnome-mines in Ubuntu-16.04 (Gnome). I am unable to find the latest links which guide through that (all are either very old or the methods suggested by them do not work). Can anyone tell me where are these high scores located.

I tried removing gnome-mines using apt-get but on reinstalling, it again showed me the same high scores.

Comment: Theres no such directory by the name `/var/games/` in ubuntu gnome 16.04

Comment: `/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps/gnomine.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/32x32/apps/gnomine.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/24x24/apps/gnomine.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/gnomine.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/apps/gnomine.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/22x22/apps/gnomine.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Xenial Xerus the high scores for gnome-mines are contained within the text file:

```
~/.local/share/gnome-mines/history
```

If this file is deleted the high scores are removed from the game...